# How to add hyperlinks dynamically to a div tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a hyperlink on the ribbon. I was able to add the hyperlink to the existing div. The Hyperlinks are getting increased by one for every action i do on the page.
How i can make it(hyperlink) restrict to one?

I am using the following code:

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Where's the cooooooddddeeeee?

Comment: Do you have any demo that demonstrates what's happening?

Comment: I am following the below code `var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); var aTag = document.createElement('a'); aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm"); aTag.innerHTML = "link text"; mydiv.appendChild(aTag); `

Comment: Edit question and put code there.

Comment: from now on...you should keep your posts like this as the new edit made to it...instead of posting code into comments..This improves readability of your question and make it much understandable for others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
```

Creates a new `anchor` element everytime it's called. Without more context it's hard to see **why and how often** this code is called.

What we do know, is every time it's called, you're ***appending*** it to the div, which is why you have multiple links.

```
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```